# Why Array Searching Error Fail for case [-2,0,10,-19,4,6,-8]

Tags: java, arrays

I have a question for my algorithm. Somehow I don't know where my code is wrong. Can someone explain to me? Thank you.

Here is the question.

```
Given an array arr of integers, check if there exists two integers N and M such that N is the double of M ( i.e. N = 2 * M).
More formally check if there exists two indices i and j such that :
i != j
0 <= i, j < arr.length
arr[i] == 2 * arr[j]
```

Test case I did not pass:

[-2,0,10,-19,4,6,-8]

Here is my code:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean checkIfExist(int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
                int temp = arr[j] * 2;
                if (temp == arr[i]){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you always compare x-th element with itself. Almost always it won't be a problem. However, in case of 0 (zero), `0 * 2 == 0` is true. All you need to do is to skip the loop iteration if `i == j`. Actually if you look closely at your task, it is stated in there that `i != j` in the formal definition.

Comment: @Henhen If my answer solved your problem you should consider accepting it.